# Gwibber leaves ghost processes behind

Tags: 10.04, gwibber, process

At some time, Gwibber is causing a ghost process, which causes an increase in consumption of the processor, so increasing temperature. Already deactivated accounts, he had configured it, but to no avail. This occurrence continues. That bothers me, because I need to kill these processes opened by Gwibber of nowhere. Here kernel generic-pae in 4GB Ram

Comment: solution - http://pprjbgbo.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/desabilitando-o-gwibber-service-no-ubuntu-10-04lts/

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. This will be closed. If this question is still valid, please add more detail and flag for it to be reopened.